# Spring Data Solr Precedence for Custom Repository

Tags: java, spring, solr, spring-data, spring-data-solr

I need to implement the following in a Spring Data Solr custom repository:

> (X OR Y) AND Z

My current code is as follows:

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria("x").is(X_VALUE);
criteria = criteria.or(new Criteria("y").is(Y_VALUE);
criteria = criteria.and(new Criteria("z").is(Z_VALUE);
```

But running this code I get the following precedence:

> X OR (Y AND Z)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The current API does not allow this combination of criteria. There's a patch attached to [DATASOLR-105](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATASOLR-105) which could help though it does not solve the problem fully.

Usage of `SimpleStringCriteria` might help for now. Please be aware of the fact, that values have to be converted to a Solr readable format.

```
new SimpleQuery(new SimpleStringCriteria("(x or y) and z"));
```

*Update*

Version `1.2` will have this issue fixed, so that its possible to create the query as follows.

```
Criteria orPart = Criteria.where("x").is("foo").or("y").is("bar");
Criteria andPart = Criteria.where("z").is("roo");
Query query = new SimpleQuery(orPart.and(andPart));
```

Comment: Thanks. I indeed ended up building the string Query and then using SimpleStringCriteria to create the criteria from it. Let's hope the patch can solve at a later stage.

Comment: But even your hint with SimpleQuery results in : x:foo OR y:bar AND z:roo, I am using spring data solr v. 1.3.0.RELEASE

Comment: hmm... you're right there still seems to be an issue. It works for `andPart.and(orPart)` which produces `z:roo AND (x:foo OR y:bar)`. Will check that and let you know once this is resolved.

Comment: The issue will be fixed in 1.4 with an enhanced concept of concatenating `Criteria` using `connect()` so that `(x OR y) AND z` can be created as `where("x").is("foo").or("y").is("bar").connect().and(where("z").is("roo"))`

Comment: Thanks. `new SimpleStringCriteria("(x or y) and z")` solved our problem.